# In XSLT 3.0 xml-to-json(), set JSON output to null

Tags: json, xml, xslt-3.0

I'm new to the XSLT

How to set null in the xslt value.

```
<string key= "Worker">        
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
</string>
```

Output:-

```
{
"Worker":""
}
```

I'm expecting value to be null instead of double quotes.

Expected Output:-

```
{
"Worker":null
}
```

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml). To define a null value you may use <Worker null="true"/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<null key="Worker"/>
```

The spec is at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-xml-to-json