# how to specify null value in map-entry

Tags: xslt-3.0

how do I express the map required to output (in json)

```
{ "foo" : null }
```

I can do
{ "foo" : "bar" }

like this

```
  <xsl:map>        
    <xsl:map-entry key="'foo'" select="'bar'"/>
  </xsl:map>
```

or this

```
<xsl:sequence select="map { 'foo' : 'bar'}"/>
```

and if you read this

> [In XSLT 3.0 xml-to-json(), set JSON output to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709929/in-xslt-3-0-xml-to-json-set-json-output-to-null)

the answer would seem to be this

```
<null key="foo"/>
```

but (I assume this should read xsl:null)?

but thats an

```
"unknown instruction xsl:null"
```

(the web seems suspiciously devoid of complete examples or references to a 'null' map-entry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah...follow your nose

```
    <xsl:map-entry key="'foo'"/>
```

the question now is, can I do this with an map 'expression'...yes

```
<xsl:sequence select="map { 'foo' : null}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `()`, i.e. an empty sequence as the map value:

```
<xsl:sequence
  select="map { 'foo' : () }"/>
```

[Online fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%20%27foo%27%20%3A%20%28%29%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=&input-type=None).

Comment: ah thats a better solution